# Diff only changed parts of lines

Tags: git, bash, diff

Is it possible to show only differences between old and new lines using `git diff`?

Here is content of file a.txt:

> 123456789

And here is content of file b.txt

> 123455789

Here is normal `git diff` output:

[image: normal output]

And here is what I'm trying to accomplish:
[image: wanted output]

I'd prefer to do this using `git diff`, but if it can't be done I'm ok with any other app.

Comment: wondering why is better insert an screenshot, instead of a simple copy&paste ;)

Comment: @jm666: Because the point is in the colors

Comment: Hm... seems, I have a bad day today. ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is what the `--word-diff` option to [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) does. Though not to that level of granularity by default.

To get single character diffs like that would require a custom `--word-diff-regex` as well. (I have `'([^[:alnum:]]|[^[:space:]])'` in a git alias here which seems to do that though. Though that wasn't the point when I wrote it.)

You can abbreviate `--word-diff=color --word-diff-regex='...'` to `--color-words='...'` too by the way.

See if [this](https://gist.github.com/deryni/8aa8d0164f620a8dcb7e) does what you want:

```
$ cat worddiff.awk
BEGIN {
    RS="\n?~\n"
    FS="\n"
}

# Special case the diff header/chunk header lines.
/^diff --git/ {
    print
    next
}

{
    delete outs
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /^[-+]/) {
            mode = substr($i, 1, 1)
            $i = ((mode=="-")?red:green) substr($i, 2) reset
            outs[mode] = outs[mode] $i reset
            outs["set" mode]++
        } else {
            gsub(/^ /, "", $i)
            outs["-"] = outs["-"] $i
            outs["+"] = outs["+"] $i
        }
    }

    # If we didn't have any changes then this is a context line and we need to
    # print it out.
    if (!outs["set-"] && !outs["set+"]) {
        print " " outs["-"]
        next
    }

    if (outs["set-"]) {
        print red "-" reset outs["-"]
    }

    if (outs["set+"]) {
        print green "+" reset outs["+"]
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
git diff --word-diff=porcelain | awk -v red="$(tput setaf 1)" -v green="$(tput setaf 2)" -v reset="$(tput sgr0)" -f worddiff.awk
```

or

```
git diff --word-diff-regex='([^[:alnum:]]|[^[:space:]])' --word-diff=porcelain | awk -v red="$(tput setaf 1)" -v green="$(tput setaf 2)" -v reset="$(tput sgr0)" -f worddiff.awk
```

That awk could probably be cleaner and there's a non-GNU awk `split` idiom to clear an array that I can't recall offhand if `delete a` is a problem.

Edit: Updated code above to match newest revision of gist. The original special case pattern was overly permissive. The original code did not handle added blank lines correctly. The updated code doesn't either but does the best that I believe is possible given the [known limitations](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Understanding-and-improving-word-diff-td5717239.html) of `--word-diff=porcelain`.

Comment: I knew about --word-diff option, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want before and after to be on two separate lines, not in the same line.

Comment: You won't be able to actually use that format of diff file anywhere but you should be able to create it with some post-processing of the default word-diff output.

Comment: @xx77aBs Does `--word-diff=porcelain` do something close enough to what you want? If not you should definitely be able to post-process that into something like what you want.

Comment: @xx77aBs Check my last edit. I think that'll do what you want.

Comment: Hey man, thanks! Seems that's it. I have one small problem - everything is white. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @xx77aBs You mean you don't get any colors in the output? Do you see `bar` in color if you run `echo "foo$(tput setaf 1)bar$(tput sgr0)baz"`? What does `printf %q\\n "$(tput setaf 1)"` output?

Comment: Echo works normally (bar is red) and print outputs "$'\E[31m'" (without double quotes). Is it working normally on you OS?

Comment: @xx77aBs Yes. It works for me. If you pipe the output to `cat -v` do you see escapes in the places you would expect to see colors?

Comment: Sorry for not responding so long. Thanks for all your help, I'll figure it out when I have some free time.